# Beautiful Soup: extracting from deeply nested <div>'s

Tags: html, beautifulsoup

Trying to extract Message text from:

```
<div class="Item ItemDiscussion Role_Member" id="Discussion_2318">
<div class="Discussion">
<div class="Item-BodyWrap">
<div class="Item-Body">
<div class="Message">
                Hello<br/>I have a very interesting observation on nature of birds in Alaska ...  <br/>
 Was there  10/19/18 has anyone heard of this     </div>
<div class="ReactionRecord"></div><div class="Reactions"></div> </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I have got this bit with:

```
tag = soup.find('div', {'class' : 'ItemDiscussion'})
```

Next I am trying to go down with:

```
s = str((tag.contents)[1])
sp = BeautifulSoup(s)
sp.contents
```

But this does not help much. How to get message text from `<div class="Message">` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can find the element from soup directly.

```
discussion_div = soup.find("div", {"class": "ItemDiscussion"})
message_text = discussion_div.find("div", {"class": "Message"}).text
```

Comment: Not in my case, I have many elements `("div", {"class": "Message"})`

Comment: check edited answer it works if only one `message` div in `ItemDiscussion` div.

Answer (score 1):

You can select any element using **select_one()** function by entering the *CSS Selector* to the element. select_one() function will only return one element if you want more than one element then you can use select() which will return a list of found elements. here is the example for you,

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
print soup.select_one("div.Item div.Discussion div.Item-BodyWrap div.Item-Body div.Message").text
```

> You can also select your element using a single class if it is
>   unique.

```
print soup.select_one("div.Message").text
```